# Jquery slide hover function showing error with .stop (But still works)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a script using Jquery which essentially moved and resizes a 1px width div. The div itself has a repeating background. Now, i'd like to point out this code works exactly as i'd like. However i noticed it was a little slow, so i looked into the console on firebug to find:

> TypeError: "#slide".stop is not a function

I'm not an expert in jquery... so i thought it best to ask here. You'll find the example here. -LINK REMOVED BY AUTHOR-

The jquery itself.

```
$("a.nav1").hover(function(){
    $("#slide").animate({ width: "65px" },{queue: false, duration: 200} )
               .animate({ left: "0px" }, 200 );

  }, function(){
    ("#slide").stop();
    }

  );


  $("a.nav2").hover(function(){
    $("#slide").animate({ width: "100px" },{queue: false, duration: 200} )
               .animate({ left: "66px" }, 200 );
  }, function(){
    ("#slide").stop();
    }

  );

  $("a.nav3").hover(function(){
    $("#slide").animate({ width: "83px" },{queue: false, duration: 200} )
               .animate({ left: "173px" }, 200 );
  }, function(){
    ("#slide").stop();
    }

  ); 

   $("a.nav4").hover(function(){
    $("#slide").animate({ width: "73px" },{queue: false, duration: 200} )
               .animate({ left: "260px" }, 200 );
  }, function(){
    ("#slide").stop();
    }

  );
```

I'm looking for the reasons behind this error. What am i doing wrong? Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#slide").stop();
^  //added $ here
```

Typo:- missing `$` sign.

Comment: Can't believe i missed that. Can't see the forest for the trees as they say. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use $ like this ==> `$("#slide").stop();`